# Consolidate SQL Server databases into 1

Tags: sql-server, database, merge, consolidation

I need to consolidate 20 databases that have the same structure into 1 database. I saw this post:
[Consolidate data from many different databases into one with minimum latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537986/consolidate-data-from-many-different-databases-into-one-with-minimum-latency)

I didn't understand all of this so let me ask like this: There are some table who have primary keys but don't have sourceID, example:

DataBase 1

```
AgencyID    Name 
1           Apple
2           Microsoft
```

Database 2

```
AgencyID   Name
1          HP
2          Microsoft
```

It's obvious that these two tables cannot be merged like this, it needs aditional column:

DataBase 1

```
Source     AgencyID    Name 
DB1        1           Apple
DB1        2           Microsoft
```

Database 2

```
Source     AgencyID   Name
DB2        1          HP
DB2        2          Microsoft
```

If this is the right way of doing this, can these two tables be merged in one database like this:

```
Source     AgencyID    Name 
DB1        1           Apple
DB1        2           Microsoft
DB2        1           HP
DB2        2           Microsoft
```

...and is it possible to do it with Transactional replication?

Thanks in advance for the answer, it would be really helpful if I would get the right answer for this.

Ilija

Comment: Is this a one off merge process?

Comment: yes, I want to merge databases into one

Comment: @ile - he is asking if it's a one-time process or will it be recurring periodically?

Comment: it will be recurring periodically

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish (application consolidation, reporting, warehousing)?  
Will the 20 databases still be used after this process is over?  Also, what are the approximate sizes of these databases as well as the number of tables in each?

Comment: I am trying to consolidate 20 databases into one and then maybe use this database for warehouse. Approximate size of each db is 5gb... it has about 30 tables. I want to merge all data to have all on one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Now I am using *Transactional Replication*. In "*Publication Properties > Article Properties*" I have to set "*Action if name is in use*" flag to "*Keep existing object unchanged*". Default is "*Drop existing object and create a new one*".
In SQL 2008 even when I change table scheme these changes are applied to consolidation database.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server's Transaction Replication has become far more flexible in 2008 than it was in SQL Server 2000. Would be nice to hear back how it works for you in the long run.

Comment: it's still not in the production but I will inform you if I run into new problems

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can do that by

**creating an DTS/SSIS package.**
Here is a [basic SSIS tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365330.aspx).

or **running SQL directly like**

```
 INSERT INTO [TargetDatabase].dbo.[MergedAgency]([Source], [AgencyID], [Name])
 SELECT CAST('DB1' AS nvarchar(16)), [AgencyID], [Name]
 FROM [SourceDatabase1].dbo.[Agency]

 INSERT INTO [TargetDatabase].dbo.[MergedAgency]([Source], [AgencyID], [Name])
 SELECT CAST('DB2' AS nvarchar(16)), [AgencyID], [Name]
 FROM [SourceDatabase2].dbo.[Agency]
```

Then call either by a **recurring [SQL Server Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx)** with one [Job Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187056.aspx) and a [Schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Don't forget to think about how you detect which row have already been copied to the target database.

Comment: This seems very complex for large databases... I actually managed to do this (on a small and simple database) using Transactional replication. The problem first time was that I didn't set "Action if name is in use" flag to "Keep existing object unchanged". Default is "Drop existing object and create a new one".

Comment: @ile (As always) it depends. If you want to have full control over the merge process you can code it in SSIS. But if Transaction Replication can now even cope with schema changes and you have lots of tables to consolidate I can see the advantages of that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Hub (http://sql-hub.com) will let you merge multiple databases with the same schema in to a single database. There is a free licence that will let you do this from the UI though you might need to pay for a license if you want to schedule the process to run automatically. It's much easier to use than replication - though not quite as efficient.